# How to Wait for more Content when Reading a File with Factor?

Tags: factor-lang

I have something like the following code

```
"file.txt" utf8 <file-reader> [ [ print ] each-line ] with-input-stream* ;
```

This works nicely for the current contents of `file.txt` and the processing (like printing in this case) ends when the end-of-file is reached. But I want the process to wait for new contents appended to the file and also process this. Or in other words, the current version implements Unix `cat`, but I want it to do `tail -f`.

I hoped `with-input-stream*` (mind the asterisk) would do the trick, as the docs say the stream is not closed at the end. But there must be something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck, I wrote a utility like that a while ago. See https://github.com/bjourne/playground-factor/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-Filesystem#tailing-a-file

```
USING: accessors io io.encodings.utf8 io.files io.monitors kernel namespaces ;
IN: examples.files.tail

: emit-changes ( monitor -- )
    dup next-change drop
    input-stream get output-stream get stream-copy* flush
    emit-changes ;

: seek-input-end ( -- )
    0 seek-end input-stream get stream>> stream-seek ;

: tail-file ( fname -- )
    [
        dup f <monitor> swap utf8 [
            seek-input-end emit-changes
        ] with-file-reader
    ] with-monitors ;
```

Your problem I think is that the quotation given to `with-input-stream*` will implicitly close the stream (`each-line` does it). I don't know if that is a bug or not. A word like this can be used to read the full stream without closing it:

```
: my-stream-contents* ( stream -- seq )
    [ [ stream-read1 dup ] curry [ ] ] [ stream-exemplar produce-as nip ] bi ;
```

Then:

```
IN: scratchpad "/tmp/foo" utf8 <file-reader> [ my-stream-contents* print ] keep
file contents here
...

--- Data stack:
T{ decoder f ~input-port~ utf8 f }
IN: scratchpad my-stream-contents* print
more file contents here
...
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Your `my-stream-contents*` approach worked right away. I will try to turn it into a workable script file. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the `tail-file` script to work. On OSX it just hangs, and on Windows it bombs (as your wiki warns) with "wrong parameter". I might come back with new questions :-). - BTW: Thanks for working on Factor.